# Gatsby create node field inside a nested field in a node

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have been trying every possible thing for the past week. Looking through docs and issues.

I query data - restaurants. Each has meals, and each meal has a image_url.

```js
restaurant {
  meals {
    [
      name: "Meal 1",
      image_url: "sksjdhfksjdhf"
    ],
    [
      name: "meal 2",
      image_url: "dfgiudgdf98g7dfg8"
    ],
  }
}
```

I want to createRemoteFileNode for each of those meal images and link to the localFile inside the meal object so that later I can query for it with `gatsbyImageData`

My gatsby-node.js is:

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  const typeDefs = `
    type Restaurants implements Node {
      id: ID
      name: String
      slug: String
      meals: [Meal]
    }
    
    type Meal {
      id: ID
      name: String
      image: File @link(from: "fields.localFile")
    }
  `;

  createTypes(typeDefs);
};


exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  createNodeId,
  getCache
}) => {
  if (node.internal.type === "Restaurants") {
    const { meals } = node;
    if(meals.length){
      await Promise.all(
        meals.map(async (meal, index) => {
          if (meal.image_url) {
            let remoteImageNode = undefined;
            try {
              remoteImageNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
                url: meal.image_url,
                parentNodeId: node.id,
                createNode,
                createNodeId,
                getCache,
              });
            } catch (error) {
              console.log("FAILED TO GET IMAGE", meal.image_url);
            }
  
            if (remoteImageNode) {
              const mealNode = ??????
              createNodeField({ node: mealNode, name: "localFile", value: remoteImageNode.id });
            }
          }
        })
      );
    }
  }
};
```

I know I need to somehow "inject" the image field into each "meal" object inside the restaurant node, but how? Do I need to somehow convert each meal object into a node?
Can anyone please show me in code how to get this done?